# Simulating Alt + Tab Key Press in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to simulate <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in R?

I've been looking for functions like `SendInput`, `keybd_event`, `SendMessage` and `SendKeys.Send` but couldn't find anything similar for R.

Some context:

I am using Rscript to plot and image that appears on the graphics device windows, then I call a function similar to `readLines()` and R waits for my input. The problem is that after the image pops up I have to go back to the terminal in order to give input and this makes my script less efficient.

I am using Ubuntu - Unity.

EDIT:

Is it possible to call bash from R? Maybe there is a function in bash that will make this possible?

Comment: Please provide additional context for your problem.

Comment: Looking to jump between console and script/s I assume?

Comment: If you are trying to do what @Honey Dipped Badger suggested, and you are also using R-Studio, this can be achieved with `CTRL+1` and  `CTRL+2`

Comment: For windows, check here: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/clear-screen-td884932.html. I think the key press for alt tab would be `"%{TAB}"`

Comment: Added some context to my problem. See edited post. Thank you all.

Comment: @Pash101 How could I implement what you're suggesting on my script? Could you make an example?

Answer (score 5):

If you are on windows, the following will work:

```
cls <- function () { 
  require(RDCOMClient) 
  wsh <- COMCreate("Wscript.Shell") 
  wsh$SendKeys("%{TAB}") 
  invisible(wsh) 
} 
cls()
```

Taken from here: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/clear-screen-td884932.html

More key presses can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using Ubuntu - Unity.

Comment: what if I am using Ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Javier2013 I'm not familiar enough with ubuntu to answer, but I think your bash suggestion is a good one. I'm not sure but I think you can access using `system(x)`, where `x` is a string of bash code.