# Simulate keyboard press with Rstudio

Tags: r

Looking for help with simulating keyboard press with Rstudio. 
My idea is to set my code to sys.sleep for some time and in meanwhile turn on the specific game (for example fifa or similar) and using Rstudio to simulate keyboard keys.

Want to train CNN / Q-learning process to manage to play a specific game in a mini situation.

Till now, checked [this option in stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568678/simulating-alt-tab-key-press-in-r), but seems it's not working anymore.

One of the ideas, I had, is to use Rcpp package to implement C/C++ code in R. Founded one example how to simulate in C++, but so far I didn't manage to implement [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531124/how-to-simulate-a-keypress) in Rcpp environment.

Any help would be really appreciated.

EDITED

My solution so far is to source Python code ([tutorial in youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTnz8wA6wpw)):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.left) 
keyboard.release(Key.left)
```

Save the code as "code.py", then on RStudio install **"reticulate"** package 
and source code in RStudio by:

```
system("python code.py")
```

Keys can be founded in youtube video (attached above).

Good day.

p.s. Working on Windows 10

Comment: I won't be able to help (no windows here), but how about sharing what you already tried?

Comment: As I mentioned, I did research and I can't find any example or "easy way" to simulate keypresses with Rstudio. 
Python, in another hand, has "PressKey" / "ReleaseKey" so it's probably possible to write "press key" part with python and then source it from Rstudio. But still, would be nice to find a straight solution in Rstudio.

Comment: Removing `rcpp` tag as this has nothing whatsoever to do with Rcpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a brand new R package `KeyboardSimulator` which is documented at

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/KeyboardSimulator/index.html